# Using jQuery to perform a GET request and using the resulting data

Tags: jquery

I have a page, let's call it "callme.html" which only has this content:

> abc

Now I want to fire the following:

```
$.get("callme.html", function (data) {

    alert(data);     

}, "text");
```

I am using jQuery 1.4.2 mini and the page is called but the alert is empty.

Any ideas why? I'd like the popup to contain `abc`

I've also tried the following

```
$.ajax({
   url: "callme.html",
   async: false,
   success: function (data) {
       alert(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: I tried it locally, but I got just “abc” returned. Do you have an example page? Did you look in e.g. Firebug's Net panel, to see if the file gets actually send (with correct headers)?

Comment: What browser? I tried with Chrome and it didn't work. I need something that will work cross-browser. I'll get back to you with an example page.

Comment: Silly question, but one worth asking - you definitely running this on a server i.e. via HTTP?

Comment: @Marcel, you can try this: http://frw.se/callme.html it actually worked in IE8 when I tied that now, but still the same in chrome.

Comment: Firefox 3.6.3, but just tried it in Chromium 5.0.375.70 (using a local web server) and still no problem, both running under Linux.

Comment: @TheDeadMedic, Why is it silly? And yes, it runs on a webserver.

Comment: That's not your example page, that's `callme.html`, containing only 'abc'.

Comment: @Marcel, The page that I try on also sets the content type to text/plain. But I get the same thing against that test page.

Comment: @Filip - because I was afraid I'd insult your intellect!

Comment: @TheDeadMedic, Ah, I thought I meant that MY question was silly :)

Comment: @TheD.: ;) there's indeed a problem with local file access. @Filip: just look at [this screenshot](http://www.flickr.com/photos/marcel-/4687650837/sizes/l/), it opened succesfully…

Comment: @Marcel, Hm this is weird. I am using Windows and Chrome 5.0.375.70. It Does work in Internet Explore but not Chrome, which is Weird!

Comment: What does 'Resources' panel of Developer Tools show you?

Comment: Filip, if the callme.html file you are calling is on a different server than the firing page, it will fail, because of the same-origin policy. Is that what's happening?

Comment: @artlung, yes they are on different ports/hosts. How do you solve that then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it with using jsonp instead and using pre-loaded images in javascript.

```
    $.getJSON("www.mypage.com?callback=?",
    function (data) {
        requestid = data.guid;
    });
```

When you provide callback=? it will be replaced by getJSON with the appropriet identifier for the callback function.

However, now I must have control over mypage.com, which I have. So problem solved!

Answer (score 1):

Use chrome's developer tool, or fire bug. This lets you see any errors, or where the request went, if it was successful, etc...

Comment: @Filip: Yes, but your rep has to be 50 to be able to comment on other's questions and answers. That said, (s)he could have simply upvoted my first comment, which said the same.

Answer (score 0):

Your `$.get()` call is fine. You need to wrap it so that it fires on load.

This works for me:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.get("callme.html", function (data) {
        alert(data);     
    }, "text");
});
</script>
```

Comment: And it *is* fired, because an alert popped up.

Comment: Filip, if the callme.html file you are calling is on a different server than the firing page, it will fail, because of the same-origin policy. Is that what's happening?

Comment: @artlung, what do you mean? Why does the files need to be on the same server?

Comment: Same-origin policy for JavaScript: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript

Comment: So how do you solve that? By setting the document.domain each time you want to create an ajax query? How does google analytics solve this when they need to query a page on a totaly different domain?

Comment: I solve it by putting the content I want to make ajax calls for on the same server. This article includes a discussion about how Google Analytics doesn't violate same-origin: http://taossa.com/index.php/2007/02/08/same-origin-policy/